# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre exec,eval y compile en python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

Me ha surgido la gran duda sobre unas funciones que he visto en internet, las cuales eran `exec()`,`eval()` y `compile()`.

Inclusive hay casos en los que se combinan estas funciones y aun no se porque, he visto documentación en linea pero la verdad, no he entendido muy bien.

Por favor alguien que me ayude a aclarar estas dudas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La respuesta puede complicarse un poco, aunque para empezar se puede resumir en lo siguiente:

Las tres sirven para recibir como parámetro una cadena que será interpretada como código python, pero cada una tiene un cometido diferente:

- `compile()` genera a partir de la cadena dada un objeto de tipo `code`, que es una especie de "código máquina" intermedio que Python usa. Todo programa python se convierte a ese código binario intermedio antes de ser ejecutado, pues el intérprete que finalmente ejecuta el programa es una especie de "máquina virtual" especifica de Python (similar a la JVM de java), que sólo comprende ese códibo binario.
- `eval()` espera que la cadena sea una expresión (aunque también admite en vez de cadena un objeto `code` como el producido por `compile()`. Retorna el resultado de evaluar la expresión.
- `exec()` admite en la cadena cualquier sentencia Python (incluso varias sentencias o un programa completo). También admite como parámetro un objeto `code` como el producido por `compile()`. Tras ejecutarlo retorna `None` (aunque la ejecución pudo causar "efectos secundarios", como cambiar el valor de alguna variable).

Ahora veamos cómo puede ir complicándose la cosa.

- ¿Qué es una expresión? Es una serie de operaciones entre variables y valores que produce al final un resultado que podría ser asignado a una variable (aunque no tiene por qué ser asignada si no se quiere). Por ejemplo, cualquier cosa que pongas a la derecha de un `=` en una sentencia de asignación, sería una expresión. También cualquier cosa que pongas tras un `if` sería una expresión (cuyo resultado final será verdadero o falso), o cualquier cosa que puedas pasar como parámetro a una función.

  `eval()` te permite que la expresión venga en una cadena.
- ¿Qué es una sentencia? En general y simplificando podríamos decir que es una línea de un programa Python. Por ejemplo una asignación es una sentencia que tiene a la izquierda del `=` una variable (o varias si usamos desempaquetado de tuplas) y a la derecha una expresión. O una línea como `while expresion:` sería una sentencia, etc. También es una sentencia `def` que sirve para iniciar la definición de una función, o `class` que sirve para iniciar la definición de una clase.

  `exec()` te permite ejecutar líneas de código que contengan una o varias sentencias, leídas de una cadena. Por tanto la cadena puede contener definiciones de funciones, de clases, etc.

Ejemplos:

```
expresion = "3*2"
resultado = eval(expresion)
# resultado vale 6

sentencias = """
def cuadrado(n):
   return n**2
"""
exec(sentencias)  # No recojo el resultado porque no hay. exec retorna None

# Ahora la función cuadrado estará definida
resultado = cuadrado(5)  # Y vale 25

# Incluso puedo hacer
expresion = "cuadrado(5)"
resultado = eval(expresion)  # Y también vale 25
```

Tanto `eval()` como `exec()` necesitan convertir la cadena que se les pasa a una secuencia de bytes en el "código máquina python", para que el intérprete pueda ejecutarlas. Para ello internamente llaman a `compile()`, pero si quieres puedes llamar a `compile()` tú mismo y guardar el código que genera, para pasárselo a `eval()` o a `exec()`. Esto puede ser útil si tienes que evaluar la misma expresión muchas veces, pues así ya la tienes compilada.

A `compile()` tienes que pasarle tres parámetros como mínimo:

- La cadena a compilar (puede ser una expresión, una sentencia, o varias sentencias)
- El nombre del fichero del cual ha sido leido el código (supongo que para que asigne el valor a la variable global `__name__`). Si no viene de ningún fichero, se le pone `"<string>"`.
- El tipo de código que es: `"exec"` , `"eval"`, o `"single"`.

Ejemplo:

```
code = compile(sentencias, "<string>", "exec")
exec(code)
# Igual que antes, esto definiría la función cuadrado()
```

## Actualización

La opción `"single"` de `compile()` está pensada para hacer intérpretes interactivos (que ejecuten lo que se llama un REPL, o sea, un *Read Eval Print Loop*, es decir, un bucle en el que se lee un comando o expresión, se evalúa, y se imprime el resultado). En otras palabras, lo que te encuentras cuando pones `python` a secas en la línea de comandos y obtienes un prompt `>>>` en el que poder probar comandos python.

Cuando le pasas a `compile()` una cadena y la opción `"single"`, el código máquina que genera `compile()` incluye una llamada a `print()` para mostrar el resultado que sale. Esto permite crear fácilmente un REPL:

```
while True:
    cmd = input(">>> ")
    code = compile(cmd, "<string>", "single")
    exec(code)
```

Comment: Que es "single"?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta