# Convertir operación representada en str a int python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy tratando de convertir una operación representada en str a int en Python. Por ejemplo:

```
numero_str = '4+5*4+20'
numero_int = int(numero_str)
print(numero_int)
```

Pero al realizarlo me surge el siguiente error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4+5*4+20'
```

Entiendo que lo más sencillo es almacenar el dato directamente como int y no como str, pero para el código completo que estoy realizando no me sirve hacer esto.
Desde ya, gracias!

Comment: Te debe servir `eval(numero_str)` tal como se muestra en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/309191/80870)

Comment: eval es una opción, pero ten cuidado si la entrada viene de fuentes no seguras (entradas de usuario por ejemplo) sin previamente sanear, te expones a inyección de código. Claro que depende del uso que le des a la app, no es lo mismo que sea un proyecto web (entonces es una locura...) que una calculadora personal con una GUI...

Answer (score 0):

ten en cuenta que aparte de los numero esa cadena de caracteres tiene caracteres como lo son el * , + , - etc, entonces no puedes hacer un casting directo de str a int, mientras tengas esos caracteres de operación, puede intentar haciendo un ciclo(for por ejemplo) que recorra la cadena y reconozca la operación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ten en cuenta que n1 y n2 son los números que están antes y después del carácter encontrado , así que seria buena idea tener un contador para saber la posición del carácter encontrado

Comment: Por favor el código como texto