# ¿Como consigo que opere la calculadora usando tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nuevo en python y para practicar estoy haciendo un programa de una calculadora haciendo uso de tkinter. He posicionado los botones y la "pantalla de la calculadora" pero me he encontrado con un problema. No se como guardar los numeros y el operador para despues realizar la operación y mostrar el resultado por pantalla. Basicamente necesito una funcion que lea la entrada y opere los numeros recibidos en función del operador seleccionado (+, -, /, *)

¿Alguna idea?

**Un pequeño disclaimer:** El codigo es un poco spaghetti ya que no he comenzado con la POO pero espero que se entienda los suficiente. Muchas gracias!!

```
import tkinter

#Ventana
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x400")
#"Pantalla"
console = tkinter.Entry(ventana, font = "Helvetica 30")
console.place(x = 25, y = 30)
#Botones primera fila
boton7 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "7", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "7"))
boton8 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "8", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "8"))
boton9 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "9", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "9"))
boton_del = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "DEL", padx = 16, pady = 20)
boton_ac = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "AC", padx = 18, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.delete(0, tkinter.END))
#Botones segunda fila
boton4 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "4", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "4"))
boton5 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "5", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "5"))
boton6 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "6", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "6"))
boton_por = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "x", padx = 25, pady = 20)
boton_entre = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "/", padx = 25, pady = 20)
#Botones tercera fila
boton1 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "1", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "1"))
boton2 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "2", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "2"))
boton3 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "3", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "3"))
boton_sum = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "+", padx = 25, pady = 20)
boton_rest = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "-", padx = 25, pady = 20)
#Botones cuarta fila
boton0 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "0", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "0"))
boton_dot = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = ".", padx = 25, pady = 20)
boton_ans = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "Ans", padx = 18, pady = 20)
boton_igual = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "=", padx = 25, pady = 20)
#Posicionando botones fila 1
boton7.place(x = 25, y = 100)
boton8.place(x = 100, y = 100)
boton9.place(x = 175, y = 100)
boton_del.place(x = 250, y = 100)
boton_ac.place(x = 325, y = 100)
#Posicionando botones fila 2
boton4.place(x = 25, y = 175)
boton5.place(x = 100, y = 175)
boton6.place(x = 175, y = 175)
boton_por.place(x = 250, y = 175)
boton_entre.place(x = 325, y = 175)
#Posicionando botones fila 3
boton1.place(x = 25, y = 250)
boton2.place(x = 100, y = 250)
boton3.place(x = 175, y = 250)
boton_sum.place(x = 250, y = 250)
boton_rest.place(x = 325, y = 250)
#Posicionando botones fila 4
boton0.place(x = 25, y = 325)
boton_dot.place(x = 100, y = 325)
boton_ans.place(x = 175, y = 325)
boton_igual.place(x = 325, y = 325)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goblanch, algo sencillo y rápido es aplicar la función `eval()` para realizar los cálculos.

Esta función nos permite evaluar la expresión de la cadena de texto y la transforma en resultado..

En tu ejemplo completé el código de los botones de `+ - * /` y al botón `=` llamamos una función `calculo()` encargada de realizar los cálculos..

Modificamos los botones para que escriban en el `console`:

```
boton_por = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "x", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "*"))
boton_entre = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "/", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "/"))
boton_sum = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "+", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "+"))
boton_rest = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "-", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "-"))
```

El botón `=` llama la función `calculo()` al ser presionado:

```
def calculo(operacion):
    if operacion != '':
        try:
            resultado = str(eval(operacion)) 
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            resultado = 'ERROR'
        console.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        console.insert(tkinter.END, resultado)
    else:
        pass
```

El código completo sería así:

```
import tkinter

def calculo(operacion):
    if operacion != '':
        try:
            resultado = str(eval(operacion))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            resultado = 'ERROR'
        console.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        console.insert(tkinter.END, resultado)
    else:
        pass


#Ventana
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("400x400")
#"Pantalla"
console = tkinter.Entry(ventana, font = "Helvetica 30")
console.place(x = 25, y = 30)
#Botones primera fila
boton7 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "7", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "7"))
boton8 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "8", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "8"))
boton9 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "9", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "9"))
boton_del = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "DEL", padx = 16, pady = 20)
boton_ac = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "AC", padx = 18, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.delete(0, tkinter.END))
#Botones segunda fila
boton4 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "4", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "4"))
boton5 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "5", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "5"))
boton6 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "6", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "6"))
boton_por = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "x", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "*"))
boton_entre = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "/", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "/"))
#Botones tercera fila
boton1 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "1", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "1"))
boton2 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "2", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "2"))
boton3 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "3", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "3"))
boton_sum = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "+", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "+"))
boton_rest = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "-", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "-"))
#Botones cuarta fila
boton0 = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "0", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: console.insert(tkinter.END, "0"))
boton_dot = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = ".", padx = 25, pady = 20)
boton_ans = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "Ans", padx = 18, pady = 20)
boton_igual = tkinter.Button(ventana, text = "=", padx = 25, pady = 20, command = lambda: calculo(console.get()))
#Posicionando botones fila 1
boton7.place(x = 25, y = 100)
boton8.place(x = 100, y = 100)
boton9.place(x = 175, y = 100)
boton_del.place(x = 250, y = 100)
boton_ac.place(x = 325, y = 100)
#Posicionando botones fila 2
boton4.place(x = 25, y = 175)
boton5.place(x = 100, y = 175)
boton6.place(x = 175, y = 175)
boton_por.place(x = 250, y = 175)
boton_entre.place(x = 325, y = 175)
#Posicionando botones fila 3
boton1.place(x = 25, y = 250)
boton2.place(x = 100, y = 250)
boton3.place(x = 175, y = 250)
boton_sum.place(x = 250, y = 250)
boton_rest.place(x = 325, y = 250)
#Posicionando botones fila 4
boton0.place(x = 25, y = 325)
boton_dot.place(x = 100, y = 325)
boton_ans.place(x = 175, y = 325)
boton_igual.place(x = 325, y = 325)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Por favor toma en cuenta que tocar validar mucho más el código para que la calculadora funcione correctamente, como por ejemplo: después que haga un resultado y presiones otro número debe limpiar la pantalla..

Cualquier otra cosa nos comentas

Comment: Obvia el comentario de arriba, me equivoqué

Muchas gracias Israel, funciona perfectamente, pero me surgen varias dudas:

1.- ¿Cómo funciona exactamente eval()?
2.- ¿Qué quiere decir ZeroDivisionError y cuál es su función?
3.- ¿Me podrías dar una idea intuitiva (sin aportar código) de como hacer para que una vez me muestre el resultado y el usuario introduzca una operación este se borre?

Muchas gracias, me fue de gran utilidad

Comment: 1- La función eval() me permite evaluar una cadena (string) y esta va a retornar el resultado de la misma.. Verifica este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309128/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-exec-eval-y-compile-en-python-3 ....  2- ZeroDivisionError:  en la función aplico un Try (que es para manejar excepciones) aqui tomo en cuenta si al momento de dividir, no lo esté haciendo entre 0 ya que genera error y se cae el programa.. Con el Try evito eso.. https://pythones.net/manejo-de-errores-y-excepciones-en-python-try-except-finally/   .... Verifica este enlace

Comment: @Goblanch como eres nuevo en la comunidad, marcar mi respuesta como aceptada es una manera de agradecer..