# Convertir Superscript a normal para la evaluar matematicamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, calculo

Estoy elaborando una pequeña calculadora y me encapriché en convertir los exponentes en súper indices(⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹) en la conversión todo okay primero usé un diccionario y luego conocí **maketrans** y opte por este último, luego con «RE» remplazo cada índice en caracteres normales concatenando con doble asteriscos para su posterior evaluación con la función **eval()**, incluso he llegado a poder evaluar una concatenación de índices **2¹²** el problema que el sistema que llegue fue de manera aislada al momento de querer evaluar más de una potencia
**2¹²+3¹²** se rompe.

```
def get_Sup(self, x):
    normal = "0123456789"
    sup_s = "⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹"
    res = x.maketrans(''.join(normal), ''.join(sup_s))
    return x.translate(res)

if self.pow:
    self.display.setText(self.display.text()+ self.get_Sup(digito))
    self.digitPSindex += self.get_Sup(digito)
    self.digitPNumber += digito
    self.dicSup[self.digitPNumber] = self.digitPSindex

for i in self.dicSup:
    if self.dicSup[i] == self.digitPSindex:
        var = re.sub(self.dicSup[i], f'**{i}', var)
return var
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **nunca** uses `eval` y... cual es la expresión regular que usas?

Comment: Me lo estaba planteando, porque motivo no tendría que usarlo?, disculpa mi ignorancia, llevo 7 meses soy pollito todavia. "re.sub" es lo que uso.

Comment: Si a tu calculadora de alguna forma le llega letras o una secuencia de bytes y lo ejecuta `eval` puede hacer de todo, desde borar las variables de tu programa hasta borrarte el sistema operativo. Puedes usar la librería `ast` y el método `literal_eval()` que es mucho más seguro

Comment: Si quieres saber del funcionamiento de `eval`,`exec` y `compile` puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/309191/183782) del gran maestro abulafia :D

Comment: sé que usas `re.sub` para reemplasar los caracteres pero no veo cual que la expresión regular (la variable `self.dicSup[i]`)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me moví a ast, por tema de probabilidad y estadísticas estuve ausente y todavía no pude encontrar la forma de hacer multiple potencias con supindices. No estaba usando expresión regular solo usaba un metodo de la libreria de RE

Comment: Sé perfectamente lo que haces y utilizas, el primer parámetro de `re.sub()` es una expresión regular y si no proporcionas eso poco puedo ayudar, ya que el problema es dela expresión regular

Comment: Lo que uso en re.sub, es un diccionario donde almaceno el superíndice y su equivalente en normal como llave, que se crea cuando self.pow está levantada. Sino, nose a que te refieres.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, hice el intercambio usando el método get_sup para comparar la expresión y el conflicto importante era que agregaba cada dígito al diccionario, lo solucione, creando otro método, que se ejecuta una vez que terminas de operar, ya sea agregando un signo matemático o le des igual.

Comment: Muy bien! Si quieres puedes compartir tu solución

Answer (score -1):

Solución: Primero que nada, obte en comparar el índice del for trasformado con el metodo get_Sup con el value del diccionario
Segundo: `self.dicSup[self.digitPNumber] = self.digitPSindex`
Agregar la potencia una vez que termina de operar y no en cada concatenación.

[image: foto de la calculadora]
[image: foto del resultado]

Comment: Esta respuesta sería valiosa si mostrara el código que propone.